# Does VS compiler provide a macro variable that tells if the floating point model is precise?

Tags: visual-c++, precision

I am implementing and algorithm that is sensitive to the type of floating point model used. It requires fp:precise to be used. Is there a macro variable that I may use to test with a static_assertion during compile time to ensure that the precise flag is used? (Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `_M_FP_PRECISE`:

```
#ifndef _M_FP_PRECISE
#error "/fp:precise not specified"
#endif
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/_nllh1)

You can find the list of predefined macros [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/predefined-macros).